# extracting specific lines containing text and numbers from log file using awk

Tags: linux, csv, awk

I haven't used my linux skills in a while and I'm struggling with extracting certain lines out of a csv log file.

The file is structured as:

```
code,client_id,local_timestamp,operation_code,error_code,etc
```

I want to extract only those lines of the file with a specific code and a positive client_id greater than 0.

for example if I have the lines:

```
message_received,1,134,20,0,xxx<br>
message_ack,0,135,10,1,xxx<br>
message_received,0,140,20,1,xxx<br>
message_sent,1,150,30,0,xxx
```

I only want to extract those lines having code `message_received` and positive `client_id` > 0, resulting in just the first line:

```
message_received,1,134,20,0,xxx
```

I want to use awk somewhat like:
`awk '/message_received,[[:digit:]]>0'/ my log.csv` which I know isn't quite correct.. but how do I achieve this in a one liner?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you want:

```
awk -F, '($1=="message_received") && ($2>0)' mylog.csv
```

If not, edit your question to clarify.

Comment: Hi Ed
Yes, that did the job, thanks! (Sorry for the late reply... I got it to work using grep | awk ... but I'm glad you showed me how I could've done it using just awk) :)